# React Js Stop map method after certain number of output

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

What should i do to stop rendering all the items from array in map() and limit to a required  number (let's say 4)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use slice method to limit the number of elements to n in the map:

```
let renderedData = this.state.elements.slice(0,n).map((element)=>{
 return (<div key={element.id}>{element.txt}</div>)
}
```

if you want to map only 4 then use 4 in place of n